# Grouped Bar Plot + SD from imported excel data

Tags: r

I've recently been trying to convert to R from Excel, and have been struggling a bit.

My goal right now is to create a grouped bar plot of the means of 2 groups: Pre-Contrast and Post-Contrast.

Each should have "Control" and "Treated" groups.

I'm not sure how to make my data reproducible (would I upload the excel sheet?)

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIUrb.png)

[This is the graph I'm trying to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJgxj.png)

```
    library(plyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)

    t2<- read_excel("t2quant.xlsx")
    summary(t2)
    colwise(sd)(t2)
```

Copy and paste from dput(t2):

```
structure(list(Pre_Contrast_Control = c(14, 10.4, 11), Pre_Contrast_Treated = c(16.7, 
    15, 12), Post_Contrast_Control = c(6, 5.8, 6.5), Post_Contrast_Treated = c(3.5, 
    3.7, 2.6)), .Names = c("Pre_Contrast_Control", "Pre_Contrast_Treated", 
    "Post_Contrast_Control", "Post_Contrast_Treated"), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I used colwise to obtain the SD of the values in  each column.
How would I go about making grouped bar plots of the mean +/- the SD of each column?

I would really appreciate the help, everyone.

Comment: `dput(t2)` and copy and paste the result would be appropriate for a reproducible example.